# Triggering a modal window using a link

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with a delete option against each row, which is a link that redirects to the delete function. I'm trying to add a modal with two buttons- cancel and delete- that gets triggered when I click on the delete link in the table. I used the following code to open the modal, but the console log showed that this error occured- `Uncaught TypeError: modalBtn is null`. Why is that? I just started learning javascript and any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the html code for the link to open the modal:

```html
<a id="open-modal" class="edit-delete" href="">Delete</a>
```

And this is the javascript code I used to obtain it:

```js
var modalBtn = document.getElementById('open-modal');
```

Comment: Did you declare several a tags with the same id? This is invalid html and therefore throws an error.

Comment: Where you put that code? Is DOM already loaded or prior loading DOM?

Answer (score 3):

There must be something else going on. You can test the below code, but i won't be able to tell you what's wrong with your code without more information.

```js
var modalBtn = document.getElementById('open-modal');
console.log(modalBtn)

function openModal(){
   confirm("delete?");
}
```

```html
<a id="open-modal" onClick="openModal()" class="edit-delete" href="">Delete</a>
```

Comment: I tried printing modalBtn using console.log() like you suggested, and it does print it, so I don't understand why I'm still getting this error(Uncaught TypeError: modalBtn is null) @Goldwave

Comment: I didn't add the rest of my code because it was mostly in Flask and everything but this is working perfectly, but if you want, I can add some more snippets. I didn't initially because I didn't think it would be useful. Maybe I can show you the rest of my javascript code?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your code, but my advice is just add attribute onclick like this

```html
<a id="open-modal" class="edit-delete" href="" onclick="openModal()">Delete</a>
```

and in the javascript code just make the function you have named before

```js
function openModal(){
    // this your function to show the modal
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong, the link to open the modal was in a loop so the same ID was being assigned multiple times.